# SQL query to get latest timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am working on this query where I have two tables ticket and comments. Now the condition is I need to fetch the latest note(timestamp) from the other table based on one field there ie: updatedAt.
This is the query I am trying to get but getting errors.

```
SELECT  t.id, t.title, t.requesterEmail, t.createdAt, c.note , t.priority, t.assigneeEmail, t.status 
FROM ticket t inner join comments  c  on  c.ticketid  = t.id   
WHERE assigneeEmail = 'bhavya.aggarwal@gmail.com' and status = 'Open' and c.updatedat = max(c.updatedat)
```

What query should i run to meet this condition.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an `ORDER BY` clause combined with a `LIMIT` clause. The former will order your "*updatedAt*" values descendently, while the latter one will select only one row (the one having the highest "*updatedAt*" value):

```
SELECT  t.id, t.title, t.requesterEmail, t.createdAt, c.note , t.priority, t.assigneeEmail, t.status 
FROM       ticket   t 
INNER JOIN comments c  on  c.ticketid  = t.id   
WHERE assigneeEmail = 'bhavya.aggarwal@gmail.com' AND status = 'Open'
ORDER BY c.updatedat DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. We can't limit it to one, the condition was I needed multiple tickets at once and all those tickets can have multiple comments on the single ticket as well. Now we need to have all the tickets but the comments on the tickets must be the latest.

Comment: can you show sample input data and expected output?  @tokyo

Comment: `{
"resource": "tickets/assigned/me",
"status": true,
"data": [
{
"ticketId": 2,
"title": "Blog",
"requesterEmail": "bhavya.aggarwal@gmail.com",
"createdAt": "2022-04-29 19:48:55",
"priority": {
"i": 0,
"name": "High"
},
"lastComment": "RESOLVED",
"assigneeEmail": "bhavya.aggarwal@gmail.com",
"status": {
"i": 0,
"name": "Open"
}
},}`

Comment: Here we are getting the value of lastComment field from another table "comments" and from that table we are having multiple comments for the same ticket id, we want to latest comment on this ticket. This is the case

Comment: You have answered with an input from a python pandas dataframe or some either language. Can you update your post with a valid postgresql input table? @tokyo

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  t.id, t.title, t.requesterEmail, t.createdAt, c.note , t.priority, t.assigneeEmail, t.status 
FROM ticket t 
  INNER JOIN comments  c  ON  c.ticketid  = t.id   
WHERE assigneeEmail = 'bhavya.aggarwal@gmail.com' AND STATUS = 'Open' AND c.updatedat = SELECT MAX(w1.updatedat) FROM comments w1 WHERE w1.ticketid = t.id
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked as per the condition.